# Hide passwords in string

Tags: regex, powershell

tl;dr 
How do I replace the word secret with ******** using regex in these cases:

```
Password="secret"
PWD="secret"
-P secret -i args
```

I'm trying to craft a regex that will detect passwords in strings and replace them with *'s (in a logging function).

I currently have this Powershell function:

```
function ScrubPasswords {
param(
    [string]$DirtyText
)
    # match any case of password="" (or PWD="") (or -P .*)
    $PwdArgRegex=[regex]'(([Pp][Aa][Ss][Ss][Ww][Oo][Rr][Dd]|PWD)=)("[^"]+")'
    $PwdArgRegex.replace($DirtyText,'$1********')
}
```

Which works just great, it replaces the password between the quotes with 8 *'s.

But I found another string that identifies a password is coming. For sqlcmd.exe the argument list is -U username -P password and I want to scrub the passwords from there.

I tried adding |(-P\s([^\s]+)\s) to the regex but it replaces the entire match string with *'s  (-P thispassword -i otherargs becomes ********-i otherargs; unwantedly stripping out the -P\s and trailing \s).

I'm doing my regex design/test at https://regex101.com/ and then when I have something that looks good I run it through Powershell_ISE.

The problem I think I have is that I have different numbers of groups on both sides of the 2nd OR "|". I'm going to keep fiddling with the parens to see if I can get the match groups to match on both sides.

I would like some help figuring this out, or maybe there's a better way to approach my goal.

This is my best effort so far:

```
((([Pp][Aa][Ss][Ss][Ww][Oo][Rr][Dd]|PWD)=)("[^"]+")|(-P\s([^\s]+)\s))
```

With these results:

```
Match 1
Full match  23-38   `-P @@@sapwd@@@ `
Group 1.    23-38   `-P @@@sapwd@@@ `
Group 2.    787-787 ``
Group 3.    787-787 ``
Group 4.    787-787 ``
Group 5.    23-38   `-P @@@sapwd@@@ `
Group 6.    26-37   `@@@sapwd@@@`
Match 2
Full match  235-250 `-P @@@sapwd@@@ `
Group 1.    235-250 `-P @@@sapwd@@@ `
Group 2.    787-787 ``
Group 3.    787-787 ``
Group 4.    787-787 ``
Group 5.    235-250 `-P @@@sapwd@@@ `
Group 6.    238-249 `@@@sapwd@@@`
Match 3
Full match  459-487 `Password="@@@NMApassword@@@"`
Group 1.    459-487 `Password="@@@NMApassword@@@"`
Group 2.    459-468 `Password=`
Group 3.    459-467 `Password`
Group 4.    468-487 `"@@@NMApassword@@@"`
Group 5.    787-787 ``
Group 6.    787-787 ``
Match 4
Full match  652-669 `PWD="@@@SAPWD@@@"`
Group 1.    652-669 `PWD="@@@SAPWD@@@"`
Group 2.    652-656 `PWD=`
Group 3.    652-655 `PWD`
Group 4.    656-669 `"@@@SAPWD@@@"`
Group 5.    787-787 ``
Group 6.    787-787 ``
```

Using this **test data**:

```
=begin data=

Result of sqlcmd -U sa -P @@@sapwd@@@ -i  C:\scripts\BridgepointScriptingLibrary\tmp\StandupScripts\common\000_SQLServer_Post_Install_Script.sql = Changed database context to 'master'.  (5 rows affected)

Preparing to run sqlcmd -U sa -P @@@sapwd@@@ -i 000_SQLServer_Post_Install_Script.sql.

Auth User="@@@NMAusername@@@" Password="@@@NMApassword@@@"
PathFromBinRoot="SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64bit).exe" PWD="@@@SAPWD@@@"

=end data=
```

Comment: It looks like your regex is matching. Perhaps the replace should be like: `$DirtyText.replace($1,'*********');` but I don't really know Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do it ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OkftZW/1)):

```
(?:(?<=Password=")\S+(?="))|(?:(?<=-P\s)\S+)|(?:(?<=PWD=")\S+(?="))
```

**Code:**

```
function ScrubPasswords {
param(
    [string]$DirtyText
)
    # match any case of password="" (or PWD="") (or -P .*)
    $DirtyText -replace '(?:(?<=Password=")\S+(?="))|(?:(?<=-P\s)\S+)|(?:(?<=PWD=")\S+(?="))', '********'
}


$testData = 
@'
=begin data=

Result of sqlcmd -U sa -P @@@sapwd@@@ -i C:\scripts\BridgepointScriptingLibrary\tmp\StandupScripts\common\000_SQLServer_Post_Install_Script.sql = Changed database context to 'master'. (5 rows affected)

Preparing to run sqlcmd -U sa -P @@@sapwd@@@ -i 000_SQLServer_Post_Install_Script.sql.

Auth User="@@@NMAusername@@@" Password="@@@NMApassword@@@" PathFromBinRoot="SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64bit).exe" PWD="@@@SAPWD@@@"

=end data=
'@

ScrubPasswords $testData
```

**Output:**

```
=begin data=

Result of sqlcmd -U sa -P ******** -i C:\scripts\BridgepointScriptingLibrary\tmp\StandupScripts\common\000_SQLServer_Post_Install_Script.sql = Changed database context to 'master'. (5 rows affected
)

Preparing to run sqlcmd -U sa -P ******** -i 000_SQLServer_Post_Install_Script.sql.

Auth User="@@@NMAusername@@@" Password="********" PathFromBinRoot="SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64bit).exe" PWD="********"

=end data=
```

Comment: Im not a regex expert - **there might be a better solution**. However, I use three non-capturing groups joined with OR together with some postive lookbehind to get the right position and a postive lookahead to leave the quote when using Password or PWD. Just look at each individual group like the first. `(?:(?<=Password=")\S+(?="))`. Maybe @Wiktor Stribiżew can improve this further :-)