# Problem with Replacing line string in XML file format file(.Config file) with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

**Objective:** To find a line in server.config file and replace with some  other value using powershell

**String that I am trying to find in that file:**

```
<add key="ReportServerUrl" value="http://ADEVSQL14\SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"></add>
```

**String to be replaced:**

```
<add key="ReportServerUrl" value="http://ADEVSQL14/SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"></add>
```

**What I tried:**

```
$filename = Get-Content "C:\target\Server.Config"
$filename -replace "<add key="ReportServerUrl" value="http://ADEVSQL14\SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"></add>", "<add key="ReportServerUrl" value="http://ADEVSQL14/SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"></add>"
```

Error which I get:

```
    ...  "<add key="ReportServerUrl" value="http://ADEVSQL14\SQL2016_INS1/Rep 
Unexpected token 'ReportServerUrl" value="http://ADEVSQL14\SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"></add>"' in expression o statement.
```

**Additional Inputs:** Though I want use this functionality as part of powershell step in Azure devops pipeline, I am trying it out at command line getting similar error

Can some one suggest please.

**Update1:**

Tried below at command line, it executes successfully but its not getting replaced.

```
  $filename = Get-Content "C:\target\Server.config" -Raw
$filename -replace '"http://ADEVSQL14\SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"','"http://ADEVSQL14/SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"'|Set-Content -Path C:\target\Server.config;
```

Comment: Is *not* a good idea to peek and/or poke directly into a serialized (xml) string (it might even expose a security hole). Instead use the related parsers. See also: [Powershell regex for replacing text between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65360515/1701026)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-operator):

> ```
> <input> -replace <regular-expression>, <substitute>
> ```

This means you can't search for a literal string that contains characters that have special meaning in a regular expression, like the backslash. Such characters must be escaped by inserting a backslash in front of them.

Try this:

```
$filename -replace '"http://ADEVSQL14\\SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"','"http://ADEVSQL14/SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"'
```

You can also use [`Regex.Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-5.0) method to automatically escape all special characters:

```
$searchStr = '"http://ADEVSQL14\SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"'
$searchStrEscaped = [Regex]::Escape( $searchStr )

$filename -replace $searchStrEscaped, '"http://ADEVSQL14/SQL2016_INS1/ReportServer"'
```

Comment: Thank you @zett42 .. that escape character \ does the trick

Answer (score 0):

A better practice is to use `#{Tokens}#` as values in the source code, and then use a `replacetokens` step during a pipeline.