# Select-String not working on piped object using Out-String

Tags: powershell

I am doing an API request which returns a bunch of data. In attempted to search through it with Select-String, it just spits out the entire value stored in the variable. This is an internet server which I am calling an api.

```
$return = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers @{"authorization" = $token} -ContentType "application/json" 
$file = $return.data
$file | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "word"
```

this returns the entire value of $file. printing $file looks like same as the pipe output. Why is this not working?

$file.Gettype says it is a system.object, another answer said to use Out-String, but something is not working.

```
$file.Gettype
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                   
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                   
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Comment: There are quiet some holes in your arguments that it is not work the way you expected. Please create a [mcve] and add an example of the $return.data to the question so that we can prove it does work (or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On closer inspection, I suspect that your issue comes from an ambiguity in the [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) documentation:

#### [`-Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string)

> Indicates that the cmdlet sends a separate string for each `line` of an
> input object. By default, the strings for each object are accumulated
> and sent as a single string.

Where the word `line` should be read as `item`.

To split you raw string into separate lines, you will need to split your string using the following command:

```
$Lines = $return.data -split [Environment]::NewLine
```

Note that this assumes that your data uses the same characters for a new line as the system you working on. If this is not the case, you might want to split the lines using an regular expression, e.g.:

```
$Lines = $return.data -split "`r*`n"
```

**So what does the`-Stream` parameter do?**

It sends a separate string for each ***`item`*** of an input object.
Where in this definition, it is also a known common best PowerShell practice to use a singular name for *possible* plural *input object**`S`***.

Meaning if you use the above defined `$Lines` variable (or something like `$Lines = Get-Content .\File.json`), the input object "`$Lines`" is a collection of strings:

```
$Lines.GetType().Name
String[]
```

if you stream this to `Out-String` it will (by default) join all the items and return a single string:

```
($Lines | Out-String).GetType().Name
String
```

In comparison, if you use the `-Stream` parameter, it will pass each separated item from the `$Lines` collection directly to the next cmdlet:

```
($Lines | Out-String -Stream).GetType().Name
Object[]
```

I have created a document issue for this: [`#7133` "line" should be "item"](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/7133)

**Note:**

> In general, [it is a bad practice to peek and poke directly into a
> serialized string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65360515/1701026)
> (including [`Json`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)) using string
> methods and/or cmdlets (like `Select-String`). Instead you should use
> the related parser (e.g.
> [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1))
> for searching and replacing which will result in an easier syntax
> and usually takes care of known issues and pitfalls.

Comment: You explanation is very informative and solved my issue. When the API returns the data, each new line has a line feed character. So splitting off by just using "`n" solved the issue with Select-String only returning one match or no matches at all.

Comment: Good answer, but the per-item explanation isn't correct - it's about in-band vs. out-of-band formatting - please see my answer; also, I suggest `"\`r?\`n"` or `'\r?\n'` as the regex.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [iRon7's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65736460/45375) with the **precise logic of [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string)'s `-Stream` switch**, as of PowerShell 7.1:

`Out-String`, like the other `Out-*` cmdlets such as `Out-File`, uses [PowerShell's rich output-formatting system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml) to generate human-friendly representations of its input objects.

- ***Without* `-Stream`**, `Out-String` only ever produces **a *single, (typically) multiline* string**.
- ***With* `-Stream`, *line-by-line* output behavior *typically* occurs - *except* for input objects that happen to be *multiline strings***, which are output *as-is*.

  - Because this exception is both obscure and unhelpful, [GitHub proposal #14638](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14638) suggests removing it.

For so-called *in-band* data types, `-Stream` works as follows, which truly results in line-by-line output:

- Input objects are formatted by PowerShell's rich formatting system, and *the lines that make up the resulting representation* are then output *one by one*.

*Out-of-band* data types are individually formatted outside of the formatting system, by simply calling their .NET `.ToString()` method.

In short: data types that represent a *single value* are out-of-band, and in addition to `[string]` out-of-band data types also comprise `[char]` and the various (standard) *numeric* types, such as `[int]`, `[long]`, `[double]`, ...

`[string]` is the *only* out-of-band type that itself can result in a *multiline* representation, because calling `.ToString()` on a string is effective no-op that returns the string itself - whether it is single- or multiline.

Therefore:

- Any string - notably also a *multiline* string - is output *as-is, as a whole*, and splitting it into individual lines requires an explicit operation; e.g. (note that regex `\r?\n` matches both Windows-style CRLF and Unix-style LF-only newlines):

  ```
  "line 1`nline 2`nline 3" -split '\r?\n' # -> 'line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3'
  ```
- If your input objects are a *mix* of in-band objects and (invariably out-of-band) multiline strings, you can combine `Out-String -Stream` with `-split`; e.g.:

  ```
  ((Get-Date), "line 1`nline 2`nline 3" | Out-String -Stream) -split '\r?\n'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`Select-String` outputs `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` objects. It seems to me that the output is somehow fancified via the PS engine or something to highlight your match, but ultimately it does print the entire matched string.

You should check out the members of the object `Select-String` provides, like this:

```
$file | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "word" | Get-Member

   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name               MemberType Definition
----               ---------- ----------
...
Matches            Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}
...
```

What you're interested in is the `Matches` property. It contains a bunch of information about the match. To extract exactly what you want, look at the `Value` property of `Matches`:

```
($file | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "word").Matches.Value

word
```

Another way:

```
$file | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "word" | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} | Select-Object -Property Value

Value
-----
word
```

Or

```
$file | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "word" | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

word
```

Comment: This seems to only get one match found, not all matches. Using ).matches.value or with the ForEach-Object. If I save the data to a file, and read it from a file it works perfectly fine. Just not with the variable pipe.