# Bring back entire select statement using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ssis

I am trying to bring back an entire select statement within a dtsx package in Powershell and having some trouble doing so. Wondering is it possible to bring back all the logic for when a sleect statement starts until it finishes. Have been able to do logic which brings back starts of a line but unsure how to bring back the entire statement. Would like to bring back everything at start of the 'Select' and end at ''. My logic so far is as below but this doesnt return all logic.
Select-String -LiteralPath Z:\Database\SSIS\Test.dtsx -Pattern 'Cast','From'

Update: after help from iRon I have gone back and tried to do the above with xml.
I have now replicated the file as xml but cant seem to find the select statement. Using the below code. My refid does match what i have in my xml file

```
  # Load the XML data from the file
$XmlData = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$XmlData.Load("Z:\Database\SSIS\test.dtsx")

# Define a regular expression pattern to match the SELECT statement
$SelectPattern = '(?s)<component\s+refId="Package\\DataFlowTask\\ODBC Source.*?<select\s+.*?<select>'

# Extract the SELECT statement from the XML data
$SelectMatch = [regex]::Match($XmlData.OuterXml, $SelectPattern)

# Output the matched SELECT statement to the console
Write-Host "SELECT statement found:"
Write-Host $SelectMatch.Value
```

Comment: Please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and try to create a [mcve] (with example data), what you actually get and what you expect as an output (see: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: As a specific comment: it looks like you trying to parse an XML file: It is generally a bad practice to peek and poke directly into a [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) string (e.g. [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)) using string methods (like `Select-String`),  Instead you should use the related parser for searching and replacing which has an easier syntax, takes care of both your issues and other pitfalls. See e.g.: [Powershell regex for replacing text between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65360515/1701026)

Comment: @iRon I have gone back and attempt to do so in xml. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @tomfbsc Except you haven't - you're still using regex to parse the file :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [iRon points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75601547/bring-back-entire-select-statement-using-powershell#comment133380825_75601547): DTSX is an XML format - treat it as XML and you'll have a much easier time parsing it.

To locate just the `<property />` node(s) that contains sql commands like in your screenshot:

```
$XmlData = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$XmlData.Load("Z:\Database\SSIS\test.dtsx")

$XPathSelector = '//property[@name="SqlCommand"]'
$XmlData.SelectNodes($XPathSelector) |ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host "Found SqlCommand node!" -ForegroundColor Green
  Write-Host $_.InnerText
}
```

Here, we use the XPath expression `//property[@name="SqlCommand"]` to only resolve `<property />` nodes, anywhere in the document, but only if they have the `name="SqlCommand"` attribute value set.

Comment: This works perfectly for me. I thought i was trying to use xml in my above code but obviously not.  I have much to learn about powershell and best ways to extract data from it

Comment: @tomfbsc You we're steering in the right direction, the problem is that `$XmlData.OuterXml` is just a string containing the original textual representation, so you never really take advantage of what you're getting by turning it into an `XmlDocument` object in the first place. It's like baking a whole cake, only to eat the icing - you could've skipped the cake and just made the icing on it's own instead :-P