# Search string on the first line

Tags: powershell, search

I'm new to using powershell.
I search for a character string at the level of the first line (only) of a file.

There are 2 cases:

- must it start with <Name
- either it can start with <sedName:Name

My idea is to search the files for the string.
Then write the number of the line found in a first field and the line in a 2nd field.
I would like to go through the loop by retrieving each time these 2 fields for processing....
My problem is that what I started doing is not working.

Thanks

```
#I locate all the files containing the desired string:
Get-ChildItem -Path $repertoire -Filter "*.xml" | Where-Object { (Get-Date ($_.LastWriteTime)) -lt (Get-Date).Date } | Select-String -List "Nom" | select LineNumber,FileName > $Rep_Trt\FileP5$Date.txt

#I tried this but it doesn't work
foreach ( $Data in  (get-content FileP5$Date.txt | foreach-object {$DocP5000 = $_ -split " " "{2 }" } -f $FileP5$Date[2]) )
```

Comment: Well, you're searching for `Nom`, not `<Name` or `<sedName:Name`

Comment: Peeking and/or poking directly into a [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) string (e.g. [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)) using string cmdlets (like `Select-String`) is a bad idea. Instead you should use the related parser for searching and/or replacing (text)nodes and attributes which has an easier syntax, takes care of most of your issues and other pitfalls. See e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65360515/1701026

Comment: You say "at the level of the first line (only)", which suggests that only the _first line_ of each should be looked at, which is not what your code does. Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and in what way your code isn't working, also taking Mathias' feedback into account.

Comment: Yes, I only search at the first line level.
Actually what I'm looking for is either:
-  "<Name" 
or 
- "<sedName:Name" .
Because there are other identical occurrences in the text that don't interest me.

Comment: I'm still unclear on what "first line level" means. If you truly mean only the first line from each file, then why would you need the `.LineNumber` property in the output, given that it is then by definition always `1`? Or do you mean that you only want the _first match_ from each file, which is what your use of `-List` suggests?

Comment: Actually, I mean the first line of each file.
And as the occurrence can be found on other lines, I started to raise the LineNumber to use it in the loop.
In fact, I want to exploit it in a second time by doing the equivalent of a grep of the line found (fields 2) and check if the first field (LineNumber) is equivalent to 1 otherwise reject the line (because that would mean it's not the first line).

Comment: @ Mathias R. Jessen
This is an error, "Nom" should be "Name".

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to look a the *first* line of each file, [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) isn't the best tool to use.

Instead:

- Use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) `-First 1` (`-TotalCount 1`) to extract the fist line...
- ... and match it against the strings of interest using the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch)

Applied to your code:

```bash
Get-ChildItem $repertoire -Filter *.xml | 
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).Date } | 
  Where-Object { ($_ | Get-Content First 1) -match '<Name|<sedName:Name' } | 
  ForEach-Object FullName > $Rep_Trt\FileP5$Date.txt
```

Note that, given that you're only ever looking at the *first* line, there's no point in including a line number in the output, so the above simply sends each matching file's full path alone to the output file.