# Powershell and windows command to perform sed operation

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, sed, powershell-2.0

I have shell command which will replace the pom version in all the pom files across the project, am trying to get the equivalent command for powershell and windows which does the required operation.

shell command:

```
find . -name "pom.xml" -exec sed -i s/1.0.1/2.0.0/g {} +
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.foo.primo</groupId>
        <artifactId>primo-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>foo</name>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile_1</id>
            <modules>
                <module>module_1</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
```

After executing `shell command` my pom.xml will look like this.

pom.xml after version replacement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.foo.primo</groupId>
        <artifactId>primo-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>foo</name>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile_1</id>
            <modules>
                <module>module_1</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
```

Version replacement would have happened in all the pom.xml files which are present even in submodule level as well.

Have tried constructing powershell command, but it is not working as intended. It is performing sed operation in only single pom.xml file, still version is not getting replaced properly.

powershell command which i have tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter pom.xml | ForEach-Object {
  $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
  $content = $content -replace "VERSION", $version
  Set-Content $_.FullName $content
}
```

Comment: You should use the `xml` parser for this. See e.g.: [Powershell regex for replacing text between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65360515/1701026). Please add a `pom.xml` example *to the question* so that this can be answered more specific.

Comment: @iRon, have added the pom.xml samples above.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, it is a bad idea to peek and/or poke in structured text using string operations as `-replace`, instead use the dedicated (`xml`) parser.
To changes the version in your `xml` file:

```
$Content = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.foo.primo</groupId>
        <artifactId>primo-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>foo</name>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile_1</id>
            <modules>
                <module>module_1</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
'@

$Xml = [xml]$Content
$Xml.project.version = '2.0.1'
```

```
[System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($Xml.OuterXml).ToString()

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.foo.primo</groupId>
    <artifactId>primo-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>foo</name>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>profile_1</id>
      <modules>
        <module>module_1</module>
      </modules>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

For your script it would look probably something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter pom.xml | ForEach-Object {
  $Content = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw
  $Xml= [xml]$Content
  $Xml.project.version = $Version
  $Xml.Save($_.FullName)
}
```